# Windows Aero Theme Not Responding-Stays on Classic

Tags: windows-7, aero

I'm attempting to change a computer (running on Windows 7) to the new Aero theme. The only problem is it stays on classic. I've tried going to the Personalizing section and choosing the Aero but it stays on the Classic theme.

Comment: Do you have LogMeIn installed or other remote viewing software. Was it working before and just stopped or never worked?

Comment: Press the start button and type aero and select the `Find and fix problems with transparency and other visual effects`. A dialog will come over and click next it will find the problem and fix it.

Comment: @avirk I did what you said but it could not find a problem.

Comment: Then check out the graphic driver does they support the 3D acceleration.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Also press the Windows+R button and run the `sfc /scannow` may be it would help and read this [article](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t155.html)

Comment: Could not find the solution there. How do I check if my graphic cards support Aero?

Comment: Tell you tomorrow right now no clue. Time to get some sleep. See this [MS support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/cannot-enable-aero/4e828db1-e58f-461b-9206-b142bb19d1f5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Windows 7 are you using? I think the `Starter` and possibly the `Basic` SKUs don't allow you to use Aero. If you've used Aero before, then the issue is you're running an application which doesn't support Aero (the more likely situation). Simply close the application, and Aero should reactivate if it's selected in the personalization window.

Comment: How about Windows 7 Enterprise?

Comment: And I all the applications I have open support the Aero theme.

Comment: Aero definately supports Aero, and should be along the lines of Ultimate in features. If you're 100% sure all the applications do (including services or background programs), then you might check that you have a working driver installed which can provide 3d acceleration.

Comment: How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @parioscreations Go into the device manager and look at who is listed as making the driver. If it's Microsoft, then you don't have proper drivers installed.

Comment: Alright, figured it out. It seems a system admin shut down the feature, for some reason...